# GPS Pull - Pulls Older Data Several Times Before Updating To Current Location

Tags: javascript, geolocation, gps, w3c-geolocation

I reviewed a few GPS problems similar. But seemed to not have much luck.  When I pull GPS by this method - it seems to pull old data, ie where last GPS pull was from.  Any suggestions?

This is a simple javascript GPS pull - that populates the form when the requested.

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 

function getLocationConstant()
{
    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {
        watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onGeoSuccess,onGeoError); 
    } else {
        alert("Your browser or device doesn't support Geolocation");
    }
}

// Get a single location update
function getLocationConstant()
{
    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess,onGeoError);
    } else {
        alert("Your browser or device doesn't support Geolocation");
    }
}

// If we have a successful location update
function onGeoSuccess(event)
{
    document.getElementById("Latitude").value =  event.coords.latitude; 
    document.getElementById("Longitude").value = event.coords.longitude;

}

// If something has gone wrong with the geolocation request
function onGeoError(event)
{
    alert("Error code " + event.code + ". " + event.message);
}
 </script>

 <div class=general align=center>
 <cfform action="gps_pull.cfm" method="post">
 <div align=center>
 <b>GPS Services Needs to be enabled on your device.</b>
 <br>
 <br>With a GPS Capable Device - Choose "Get Location". Once the GPS data is pulled in, choose "Add GPS".
 <br><span class=code8>You may need to allow GPS Device time to pull current location</span>
 </div>
 <br>
 <table align=center>
 <tr>
 <td>Latitude:</td>
 <td><cfinput type="text" id="Latitude" name="gpslat" value="" required="yes" message="Choose Get Location First"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Longitude:</td>
 <td><cfinput type="text" id="Longitude" name="gpslong" value=""></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td colspan=2 align=center><br><input type="button" value="Get Location" onclick="getLocationConstant()"/> &nbsp; <input type="submit" value="Add GPS"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <input type="hidden" name="src" value="gpsup">
 </cfform>
```

Comment: So is your question "Why does `watchPosition` not continually update?"

Comment: Yeah I guess, or should I be using something different?  It will take several pulls to get the right position - sometimes about 5 or more.

Comment: I'm trying this: changing watchPosition to getCurrentPosition - according to http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html - it is a one time GPS pull - I'll test some more

Answer (score 0):

watchPosition can take options: `watchPosition(onGeoSuccess,onGeoError,options);` and the default values are

```
options = { "enableHighAccuracy": false,
            "timeout"           : Infinity,
            "maximumAge"        : 0 }
```

It may be that your GPS device doesn't record small changes in position unless `enableHighAccuracy` is `true`. When it notices the position change, `onGeoSuccess` is called again. And you can force the position to be found again by recreating the watch (but the position held by the GPS may not have changed because of the `enableHighAccuracy` setting).

`enableHighAccuracy` is also applicable to `getCurrentPosition` options, and will work in the same way.

Comment: Trying now - had the max age added - and removed the watch position stuff - just trying with getCurrentPosition - thx for insight so far

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have the code down too. Still pulls old data, usually take 3+ pulls to get correct data.  Using Android Samsung Galaxy S2 - have tried with GPS mode only and GPS + Cell Triangulation.  And still takes 3+ pulls usually to get right data.

Ideas folks?

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 

// Get a single location update
function getLocationConstant()
{
    if(navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess,onGeoError,{enableHighAccuracy:true,maximumAge:0});
    } else {
        alert("Your browser or device doesn't support Geolocation");
    }
}

// If we have a successful location update
function onGeoSuccess(event)
{
    document.getElementById("Latitude").value =  event.coords.latitude; 
    document.getElementById("Longitude").value = event.coords.longitude;

}

// If something has gone wrong with the geolocation request
function onGeoError(event)
{
    alert("Error code " + event.code + ". " + event.message);
}
 </script>
```